# printing multidimensional array in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print an array with specific dimensions, but it prints out wrong entities when it's run.

```
//code
#include <stdio.h>

int my_array[2] [4] = {
{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}
};

void print_array(const int h, const int w, char array[][w]) {
   int nRow = h;
   int nColumn = w;
   for(int i = 0; i < nRow; i++)  {
        printf("--- Row %d --- \n", i);
        for(int j = 0; j < nColumn; j++) {
            printf("Column [%d] = %d \n", j, array[i] [j]);
        }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const int array_width = 4;
    const int array_height = 2;
    print_array(array_height, array_width, my_array);
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling it prints out the next result:

[image]

Comment: `char array[][w]` should be `int array[][w]`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani And that should be posted as an answer instead.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani thanks, it worked just fine after changing it as you said.

Comment: Did you compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yeah

Comment: Then, it gave you some warning, and you should have corrected your code to get no warnings.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude I didn't know how to stretch that to an answer!

Comment: @SpongeBobSquarePants doesn't Microsoft allow copying text from the console? Your output should be included as text, not as a screenshot of text where the text is a relative unreadable 5pt.

Comment: When using gcc, note that it is in "trash mode" by default. Compile with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra` to prevent it from letting bad, non-standard code through.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani "Stretching" that to an answer is no so hard. Copy the line into the edit field below. Use some newlines for formatting. Then make a little text starting with "This line ..." and continuing with "because ...". Mention different sizes of `char` and `int` and your guesses what they are. The question is not world class, but it is not off-topic. So you should even be safe from downvotes by people from the "good answers to off-topic questions are bad answers" clan.

Comment: Voting to close as typo

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `char array[][w]` to `int array[][w]` in the function `print_array`, which expects integer array. The compiler would have issued incompatible type warning, but that's easy to miss! Try to compile the program with zero warnings.